# React JS Can I use react in multiple apps on a site

Tags: reactjs

Say you have a project that has multiple different apps such as online store, booking appointment, etc. Can React JS be used for the different apps or is it limited to single-page apps?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. That a site is a "single page" is orthogonal to what anything on that page does, i.e., the "single page" might share a header and footer, but all other content is completely different.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you sure can.

You can mount different apps to different places on existing pages and they all work independently.

For example you could mount two apps to different places on an existing page like so:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import OnlineStore from './online-store'
import Booking from './booking'

ReactDOM.render(<OnlineStore />, document.getElementById('online-store'))
ReactDOM.render(<Booking />, document.getElementById('booking'))
```

Comment: Thanks, but document.getElementById is residing in a document.  But, each app has their own CRUD pages and other pages depending on the business logic.  So, how do you mount different apps to different places on different pages?

Comment: It's up to you to call [`ReactDOM.render()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render) to mount react apps to the pages you want in the locations you want. So for the pages that you want to contain a react app, you could (for example) add a script tag to those pages that calls `ReactDOM.render()` and mounts what you want.

Comment: To make things clear, can you edit your answer for mounting to different pages inside different apps. Ideally, I'd create a folder under the project src root and call it say UI.  Then, I'll create the react app there.  So, what then? Do you go to index.js of the src folder? Or, do you go to each app and import React in each page you want to use React in? If you could update your answer to give a more clear flow, it would help address the original question

Comment: @EarlyCoder We may be having a terminology issue. You say "create a React app"; do you mean by doing a `create-react-app` or equivalent? That is unnecessary. What you need are *components*, not "apps".